# Json service returns as HTML

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, json

I'm calling a third party JSON service

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:BASE_JSON_URL, address];
    NSURL* urlAddressJSonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    dispatch_async(globalQueue,
                   ^{
                       NSData* addressData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAddressJSonUrl];

                       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resolveFromJSonResult:)
                                              withObject:addressData waitUntilDone:YES];
                   });
```

copy&paste the urlString into a browser results in status ok and I get my JSON object as dictionary.
Converting `NSData` result to `NSDictionary` as follows results in nil

```
NSDictionary* jsonAddressResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

also tried in `options` parameter the following: `kNilOptions` and `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers |NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` but I still got nil.

transforming `NSData` to `NSString` reviled that the result is HTML:

```
(null)<style>body{color:#black;} span.q{color:#FF0084;} span.ns{color:#0259C4; font-weight:bold;} span.n{color:#666666;} span.at{font-weight:bold;}</style><pre>{ "<span class="ns">places</span>": { 
    "<span class="ns">place</span>": [
      { "<span class="at">place_id</span>": "<span class="q">RaZZuVZQW7xqJM2P</span>", "<span class="at">woeid</span>": "<span class="q">1968212</span>", "<span class="at">latitude</span>": <span class="n">32.045</span>, "<span class="at">longitude</span>": <span class="n">34.769</span>, "<span class="at">place_url</span>": "<span class="q">\/Spain\/Tel+Aviv\/Tel+Aviv</span>", "<span class="at">place_type</span>": "<span class="q">locality</span>", "<span class="at">place_type_id</span>": <span class="n">7</span>, "<span class="at">timezone</span>": "<span class="q">Asia\/Jerusalem</span>", "<span class="at">_content</span>": "<span class="q">Madrid, Madrid, Spain</span>", "<span class="at">woe_name</span>": "<span class="q">Madrid</span>" }
    ], "<span class="at">query</span>": "<span class="q">Madrid, Spain</span>", "<span class="at">total</span>": <span class="n">1</span> }, "<span class="at">stat</span>": "<span class="q">ok</span>" }</pre>
```

how can I transform this to JSON or better yet extract the data I need?

Comment: More data is ended to answer. Please supply your request headers.

Answer (score 1):

first off you must always have a definite understanding of exactly what kind of data your REST resource is returning (ie rather than trial and error like what you're doing) using tools such as [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) gives you the `content-type` header of the response:

[image]

using that information, and using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (which makes such tasks much easier), you can register your response type like so:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = 
    [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kApiBaseUrl]];
// notice that request parameter encoding may very well be of type json, that's 
// not the same as the return header being json or html etc
client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
// here you are setting the return header as 'text/html' b/c that's what 
// exactly what it is, if postman said it was of type 'application/json' 
// then you'd put that here
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/html"];
```

then you can [post](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.2/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/postPath:parameters:success:failure:) or [get](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.2/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/getPath:parameters:success:failure:) like so:

```
NSString *postPath = @"your api resource path";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"param1name": param1value,
                         @"param2name": param2value}; // your request params

[client postpath:postPath parameters:params 
       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON){
   // here you convert the JSON into an array like structure
   id payload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON 
                                                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments 
                                                  error:nil];
   // process payload
   NSString *fname = payload[@"fname"]; //etc
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
   // handle error
}
```

I recommend you read on the docs of [JSONObjectWithData:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:) especially the options part.